# I am having 2 tables, 1st is friends and 2nd is post

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, view

Please find all the tables which I am using for the wall.

1. I want to check if the person is in my friends list.
2. If he is there in my friend list, display the posts related to that friend.

**Candidate Table**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `candidate` (
  `id` int(200) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `designation` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `pic` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;
```

**friends**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `friends` (
  `id` int(200) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cand_id` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `request_date` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `friend_id` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `accept_date` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

**posts**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `post` (
  `post_id` int(200) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cand_id` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `post_email` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `post` varchar(2000) NOT NULL,
  `post_image` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `post_date` date NOT NULL,
  `like` int(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`post_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=11 ;
```

**view for viewing the posts**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `post_view` (
`post_id` int(200)
,`post_email` varchar(200)
,`post` varchar(2000)
,`post_image` varchar(500)
,`id` int(200)
,`name` varchar(200)
,`email` varchar(200)
,`designation` varchar(200)
,`pic` varchar(200)
);
```

Comment: I can't see any query tried. Is there any error or what? Use `INNER JOIN` and will work.

Answer (score 0):

Question 1 ans :- 
select * from candidate where id in(select friend_id from friends where cand_id=2) or id in (select cand_id from friends where friend_id=2)

here, I  assume  that cand_id column is send request to other candidate,so 'friend_id' column is a ultimately candidate id as a friend id.
this sub-query first check to cand_id and select friend_id to outer query result.
or condition to check to friend_id compare and select cand_id to outer query result.

example.
        you have a candidate.your candidate id is 1.
        other  candidate id is 2.
        and I am also candidate so my candidate id is 3

```
    after your have send request to candidate id 2
        now table entry is 
            cand_id=1  friend_id=2

        now,  candidate 2 send friends request to candidate 3 
            table entry is  
                    cand_id=2  friend_id=3
        now this scenario 
                    candidate 2 =total friends is 2 (candidate 1 & 3 )
```

Question:- 2 
        select * from post where cand_id in (select id from candidate where id in(select friend_id from friends where cand_id=3) or id in (select cand_id from friends where friend_id=3))

```
        here, only display to my friends list post
```

Answer (score 0):

Query for the first question can be something like:
SELECT * FROM candidate c, friends f WHERE c.name = f.name;
That basically gathers all the candidate names that also exist in the friends table. You can expand that using a AND for the third table.

However, that is quite basic SQL querying and you should have been able to find it using some google.

or use the answer below me, posted while i was typing this answer.